# Can't boot Peppermint 32 bits in VirtualBox 6.1.40 - kernel does not have PAE

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 32bit, pae, peppermint

In a laptop of 64 bits with Windows 7 as host with VirtualBox 6.1.40 installed, was created a Virtual Machine for the latest Peppermint OS available at [Choosing and Downloading a Disk Image](https://peppermintos.com/guide/downloading/). I got the `PeppermintOS-i386.iso` file and the Virtual Machine is based on Debian 32 bits with 2GB of ram.

When the `.iso` file is booted, appears the welcome screen with:

```
PeppermintOS - Live

PeppermintOS (686-pae)
PeppermintOS with Localisation support >
Utilities                              >
Recovery Options                       >
```

Is selected the `PeppermintOS (686-pae)` option and appears a new screen with the following message:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

The goal is get some experience with Peppermint 32 bits to be installed really in other old laptop based on 32 bits.

How fix this situation? I am assuming some setting should be applied for VirtualBox in some place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Virtual Machine stopped and selected

```
Open Settings
 System
  Processor
   Check the 'Enable PAE/NX' checkbox
```

Done